# How to preserve inline CSS style with lxml.html.clean.Cleaner() in Python?

Tags: python, lxml, lxml.html

I am trying to clean up an HTML table using lxml.html.clean.Cleaner(). I need to strip JavaScript attributes, but would like to preserve inline CSS style. I thought style=False is the default setup:

```
import lxml.html.clean
cleaner = lxml.html.clean.Cleaner()
```

however when I call `cleaner.clean_html(doc)`

```
<span style="color:#008800;">67.51</span>
```

will become

```
<span>67.51</span>
```

Basically, style is not preserved. I tried to add:

```
cleaner.style= False
```

It doesn't help.

Update: I am using Python 2.6.6 + lxml 3.2.4 on Dreamhost, and Python 2.7.5 + lxml 3.2.4 on local Macbook. Same results. Another thing: there is a javacript-related attribute in my html:

`<td style="cursor:pointer;">Ticker</td>`

Could it be lxml stripped this JavaScript related style and treated other styles the same? I hope not.

Comment: What versions of Python and lxml do you use?

Comment: Hi, mzjn, thanks for your comment! Please see updates.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It works if you set `cleaner.safe_attrs_only = False`.

The set of "safe" attributes ([`Cleaner.safe_attrs`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.clean.Cleaner-class.html#safe_attrs)) is defined in the `lxml.html.defs` module ([source code](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.defs-pysrc.html)) and `style` is not included in the set.

But even better than `cleaner.safe_attrs_only = False` is to use `Cleaner(safe_attrs=lxml.html.defs.safe_attrs | set(['style']))`. This will preserve `style` and at the same time protect from other unsafe attributes.

Demo code:

```
from lxml import html
from lxml.html import clean

s ='<marquee><span style="color: #008800;">67.51</span></marquee>'
doc = html.fromstring(s)
cleaner = clean.Cleaner(safe_attrs=html.defs.safe_attrs | set(['style']))

print html.tostring(cleaner.clean_html(doc))
```

Output:

```
<div><span style="color: #008800;">67.51</span></div>
```

Comment: It indeed works! Thanks a lot. Now I am wondering why style=False won't work. I guess it might because of this code, some trade-off between javascript and style (AND safe_attrs). 
Thanks for the workaround and showing me the source code to read more

Comment: It's nice solution!